# Can I make Github action exclude runs if merging certain branches?

Tags: github, github-actions

In the [`node-newrelic` repo](https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/blob/34376d7d51c0e0d34a5c94b53785d153341f06b8/.github/workflows/ci-workflow.yml), we work by regularly squash-merging commits to the `main` branch and running CI (tests, linting, coverage) on each push to the main branch:

```yaml
name: Node Agent CI

on: [push, pull_request, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  lint:
    # etc
  unit:
    # etc
  integration:
    # etc
  #etc
```

The problem is when we create release branches. Because we regularly merge to `main`, release branches only update metadata like `NEWS.md` and update the version number in `package.json`. We can easily exclude release branches from running CI when the PR is created (i.e. filter by branch name), but we would like to also exclude the action from running when we merge to `main`. We cannot filter by branch when merging, because there is no source branch name for the `push` event in Github Actions.

Note that we also cannot exclude release branches by files, because some changes to `package.json` are purely metadata changes (e.g. changing the version number) and some are code changes (e.g. updating the dependencies to handle a security update).

The only solution I can see is to use [event context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#viewing-all-properties-of-an-event) to see what files were touched by the `push` event and then write elaborate logic to inspect the diff.

It would be easiest if we could filter merges (pushes) to `main` by the branch the merge came from, but this information is not available in the push event context. So what can we do instead?

Comment: You could remove **push** as event that can trigger your workflow and keep only **pull_request** (and workflow_dispatch).
Then your workflow would be triggered when your pull request is opened, synchronized or closed.
By triggering your workflow with a pull request event rather than a push event, you can know which is the branch your merge come from.